# срезы в dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, slice

[image: Данные с результатом]

Есть данные. В столбец Range New необходимо получить SN Range Start[: длина].

Заранее спасибо.

Comment: На скрине в Range New попадают первые символы SN Range Start, а не SN Range Stop. На скрине ошибка или в тексте? Для какого столбца делать в итоге slice?)

Comment: Да, вы правы, опечатка. Для старт

Comment: Данные нужно приводить в воспроизводимом виде, т.е. в виде **текста** кода программы, который можно запустить и попробовать с ним что-то сделать.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Можно применить построчный .apply.

```
df['Range new'] = df.apply(lambda x:df.iloc[x['SN Range Start']:x['SN Range Start']+x['длина']], axis=1)
```

С помощью метода .apply применяем lambda функцию к каждой строке (axis=1). Функция берет данные из двух исходных столбцов и возвращает нужный срез в новую колонку.

Answer (score 3):

Написал небольшую функцию, на вход она принимает оригинальный датафрейм, а на выходе заполняет столбец Range_new слайсами нужной длины. Функция проходится по всем строкам и составляет список слайсов, а затем заполняет этим списком столбец Range_new. Названия столбцов и датафрейма можете поменять, чтоб подходили к вашему датафрейму.

```
def range_new(df):
    range_n = []
    for x in range(0, len(df['SN_Range_Start'])):
        i = df['SN_Range_Start'].iloc()[x][:(df['длина'].iloc()[x])]
        range_n.append(i)
    df['Range_new'] = range_n
    return None

range_new(df)
```

Comment: во-вторых, слово "длина" пишется с одной буквой "н", во-первых, вы как-то игнорируете векторизованные подходы pandas.

Comment: @strawdog, спасибо, видимо когда код писал-не заметил ошибки)
По поводу векторизованных подходов-я пока что новичок в pandas, так что слышу про это в первый раз если честно, буду признателен если поделитесь какой-нибудь ссылкой, где можно почитать про эти подходы)

Comment: ну вот посмотрите на "соседний" ответ. - там векторизация достигается за счет метода apply. хотя, даже это - не лучший пример. вы же ходите по датафрейму циклами - а это святотатство просто. сама суть pandas - в векторизации вычислений, когда можно сразу работать со столбцами и строками.

Comment: @strawdog ну метод apply() я знаю, и когда писал код-понимал, что вероятно есть более удобный и быстрый способ с использованием других методов, которых я не знаю или попросту не додумался использовать. Если есть свободное время, можете подсказать как бы вы написали код и какие методы использовали бы, я постараюсь это запомнить) Я пока что только учусь, заранее спасибо)